# How to get UTM from Latitude/Longitude using Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

I am looking for a way to convert from WGS84 to UTM Zone 21

I've only found a `SDO_CS.TO_USNG` function in oracle spatial, but this converts to United States National Grid (USNG), this is the example

```
Select SDO_CS.to_USNG( 
             SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001,8307,
                           SDO_POINT_TYPE(-57.5451,-25.2371,NULL),
                           NULL,NULL), 
                     1
                     ) UTM_MGRS 
 from dual;

_______________
21JVN4510008687
```

The conversion to UTM would be x=445099,61395302, y= 7208686,7337054

Comment: What UTM zone are you trying to convert to?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Zone 21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [transform()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_cs_ref.htm#CACFCGDE) function of [sdo_cs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_cs_ref.htm) package to do conversion:

```
select t.sdo.sdo_point.x as x
     , t.sdo.sdo_point.y as y
  from (select sdo_cs.transform( 
                       sdo_geometry( 2001
                                   , 8307  --Longitude / Latitude (WGS 84)  SRID
                                   , SDO_POINT_TYPE(-57.5451,-25.2371,NULL)
                                   , null
                                   , null)
                             , 82288       -- UTM Zone 21 SRID
                            ) as sdo
        from dual
      ) t
```

Result:

```
 X            Y
----------   ----------
445099.614   7208686.74
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above. One way to find the SRID that you need (e.g. the 82288 used above) is to query the cs_srs table.

```
select cs_name, srid from cs_srs where cs_name like '%UTM Zone 21%';
```

S_NAME                                                                                SRID

---

UTM Zone 21 (NAD 27 for Canada)                                                       82281
UTM Zone 21 (NAD 83)                                                                  82282
UTM Zone 21, Northern Hemisphere (Corrego Alegre)                                     82283
UTM Zone 21, Northern Hemisphere (SAD 69)                                             82284
UTM Zone 21, Northern Hemisphere (WGS 84)                                             82285
UTM Zone 21, Southern Hemisphere (Corrego Alegre)                                     82286
UTM Zone 21, Southern Hemisphere (SAD 69)                                             82287
UTM Zone 21, Southern Hemisphere (WGS 84)                                             82288

8 rows selected.